# For some reason labels does not rotate in css

Tags: html, css

I want to rotate a label, but transform: rotate(); does not seem to work. Any ideas why?

css code

```
#labelName{
    position:relative;
    width: 50px;
    bottom: 150px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

http code

```
<input type="text" id="something" placeholder="something"> <label for="something" id="labelName">mm</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make it a block element with `display: block`. Inline elements can't be transformed.

```css
#labelName{
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<input type="text" id="something" placeholder="something"> <label for="something" id="labelName">mm</label>
```